# Font-face embedded fonts look fuzzy in Windows 7 browsers

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using a font called Chunk Five and when embedded with font-face, it looks almost unreadable in windows 7 browsers because of the way Windows renders their fonts (it's too fuzzy and thick). I've tried modifying things like font-weight and text-shadow, but they don't have any effect. Is there any way to change this or will I have to resort back to cufon?

Comment: Do you have ClearType enabled and configured for yourself (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/337-cleartype-text-tuner.html)?

Also, are you using CSS syntax that is compatible across the different browsers (http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator generated markup.

Comment: Yes everyone it is a Windows clear type issue, but just changing my own settings in Windows isn't going to help everyone else! The font squirrel generator that Alex K posted is perfect, it generates everything you need to take into account multiple browser/platforms.

Comment: Are you sure it generates everything you need? Unfortunately, for my non-English fonts the squirrel generator doesn't work for any browser (ie it's useless, sorry). But can you tell us what the squirrel generator could be doing to fix the smooth/cleartype rendering issue in particular? I have a squirrel-generated font pack with me now, and I can't see how it is solving this issue specifically - it mainly solves cross-browser issues.

Comment: The font squirrel generator solved the same issues for me (jagged fonts on every windows browser). I guess it adds hinting/other info that helps the windows font rendering engine suck less. For non-english fonts, you can use the expert settings to make sure all the characters are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a ClearType problem? You could try toggling the ClearType renderer, to see if that makes a difference either way. If ClearType is on, you could try tuning it with the ClearType Tuner app for your viewing preferences.