# Font becomes pixelated after placing div in middle of screen

Tags: html, css

The font within the div provided is pixelated (h3,p). I don't think its my computer or browser settings because the font outside of the div aren't pixelated. The pixelated appearance happens after I centre the div within the middle of the screen in the .popupBoxWrapper. Here is the code related to the div, any idea what could be causing the problem?

HTML:

```
<div id="popupBoxOnePosition">
  <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
    <div class="popupBoxContent">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');">
        <button class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none'">X</button>
      </a>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Example</p>
      <p>lineone</p>
      <p style="font-size: 15px;">Follow us on Instagram @sharegoodmessages</p>
      <p style="font-size: 15px;">Follow us on Twitter @SgmEnglish</p>
      <br>
      <p style="font-size: 15px;">Developed by example</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">

  <a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');"><img src="info_button.png"></img>
  </a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popupBoxOnePosition{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.popupBoxWrapper{
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: left;
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.popupBoxContent{
    background-color: GhostWhite;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    display: block;
}

.close{
    border:0px;
    float: right;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: GhostWhite;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    right: 25px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may only occure in your browser or OS, depending on the pixel-rendring. The chosen font may also have an impact.

Quick and easy you could try to add this to the CSS:

```
.popupBoxContent {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Or this to the text using the font (Stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18536114/3938741)):

```
// try around, find the setting that fits your font-size
webkit-text-stroke: 0.6px; 

// alternative RGBa syntax, allows finer settings with alpha-transparency
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

Anyway, there are plenty of answers out there which answer more in depth why it occures, and there might not be any easy solution. You can also read further [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/645).