# Wordpress, fonts looking ugly

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I'm having a problem with some fonts, and it does affect many different fonts.

I'll add a picture to explain the problem.

The font can be seen **[here](http://tordenfryd.com)**

Futura is used on the header of the first post.

[image]

Comment: Is this a browser-specific issue?

Comment: Well, not really. It looks slightly better in explorer, but thats just because explorer has added some "blur"

Comment: In the CSS file, try adding to the font a default font: **font:Futura, sans-serif;** for example. That way the browser will use the default font if does not find Futura. You coud also use **imagettftext()** to solve the problem.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with @font-face.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858560/font-face-embedded-fonts-look-fuzzy-in-windows-7-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Are you using google fonts? I've had very poor results with them. I'm not sure how your theme has its fonts set up but you could try switching services. Or upload the font to your server and use [@font-face](http://www.font-face.com/)

Which would look something like this in your CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Futura;
    src: url(http://www.font-face.com/fonts/futura/Futura.ttf);
    font-weight:400;
}

h1{
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
}
```